# Pass this to child Function

Tags: javascript, mysql

This function should get some data out of a MySQL database:

```js
function getXXX() {
  this.output = []
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err
    con.query('SELECT * FROM `XXX`', function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      this.output = result
    })
  })
  return this.output
}
console.log(getXXX())
```

how do i pass `this` to the child function because right now it returns []?

(I basically want a function that returns the values from the database)

Comment: Which kind of "child function" are you talking about?

Comment: The function given to the conn.querry function needs the variables of the getXXX function

Comment: The `result` that you get from the con.query is only available in the scope of the callback. If you try to access this.output outside of it, you will always get `[]`. If the `con.query` returns a promise you could return it and use the resolved value elsewhere wherever the promise gets passed. Read more about [promises](https://web.dev/promises/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current implementation, `getXXX` returns *before* `con.query` executes the callback which you pass as its second parameter.

One way to get the `result` back to the context in which you call `getXXX`, without having to worry about passing `this` around, would be to return a Promise:

```
function getXXX() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return // return early to prevent further execution below
      }
      con.query('SELECT * FROM `XXX`', function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
          return // return early to prevent further execution below
        }
        resolve(result)
      })
    })
  })
}

// getXXX now returns a promise so you can use .then and .catch
getXXX().then(data => {
  // work with your data here
}).catch(err => {
  // handle the error
})
```

You may want to read up on asynchronous patterns in javascript, this is a good resource to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to pass "this" to the inner function

```
//Use arrow function that stores "this" automatically

function getXXX() {
    this.output = []
    con.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        con.query('SELECT * FROM `XXX`', function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err
            this.output = result
        })
    })
    return this.output
}

//Bind "this" with .bind function

function getXXX() {
    this.output = []
    con.connect((function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        con.query('SELECT * FROM `XXX`', function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err
            this.output = result
        })
    }).bind(this))
    return this.output
}
```

Comment: it still throws [] back.

Comment: maybe result is empty? :)

Comment: Aaahh ... 
Seems that I understand the problem

You expect that this.output will contain the request's result, right?

No it will not :(

See the answer above

Comment: Generally I would like a function which returns the data from the SQL querry.